# How I can cast a string to XML file in R?

Tags: xml, r, string, casting

I have a String variable `xml <-'<Model>......'`. I want to cast this variable to XML File and then export this file as xml file in my disk. How I can do this?
I can't use the library `xmlview` because for my version of R is not availaible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `XML` package

```
(xml <- xmlParse(xml))
saveXML(xml, file = "my.xml")
#> [1] "my.xml"
```

Comment: thanks for your response, however, with the method newXMLNode, I can't parse the string completely. I try newXMLDoc too but doesn't work